# Using Webkit-Sharp in a C# project

Tags: c#, .net, webkit

I'm trying to use Webkit-Sharp to implement a simple HTML browser in my application. I'm using Microsoft Visual C# Express Edition with the hopes of eventually moving the code over to Linux under Mono.

My first step was to add references to all of the Webkit dll files.

Next, I went and added the WebKitBrowser controls to the toolbox in the standard way and dropped a WebKitBrowser control on my form (specifically, on a TabPage.

I added the needed using statements of using WebKit; and using Webkit.Interop; to my declarations. My webkitBrowser control is called myBrowserControl.  As I understand it, I should be able to do things like

```
myBrowserControl.Navigate('http://www.google.com');
```

and the browser should take me to Google's homepage. But, for some reason, it doesn't understand what WebkitBrowser is. In my Form Designer code, I have the following line:

```
private WebKit.WebKitBrowser myBrowserControl;
```

and I am being told that WebKitBrowser doesn't exist in the WebKit namespace and I may be missing a reference to an assembly. But it doesn't seem like I am. Can anyone help me figure this out? I know I'm doing something simple wrong but I can't figure out what.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just posting in case someone else finds this.

Were you trying to drop a WebKit gtk control into a Winforms project? That doesn't work. You might possibly be able to do this if you're using gtk on windows, although I've heard no one has had any success getting webkit-sharp working in windows.
You could actually use the winforms browser control in windows, since there is a (now unsupported) winforms port in mono.